# unauthorized error code when accessing PARSE.COM

Tags: c#, rest, parse-platform

I use the code bellow to access class Book on Parse.com

```
    public void GetBook()
    {
        string RequestString = "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Book";
        string ApplicationId = "my Application ID";
        string RestApiKey = "my REST API Key";

        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(RequestString);

        NetworkCredential streetCred = new NetworkCredential(ApplicationId, RestApiKey);
        webRequest.Credentials = streetCred;
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Timeout = 100000;
        HttpWebResponse b = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
    }
```

This always results in a 401 Unauthorized response.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, I don't think `RestApiKey = "my REST API Key"` is a valid key. Also the `ApplicationId` looks suspect. Unless of course you blanked these out to post your question? If so, ignore this :)

Comment: in the actual code there are real values, copy pasted from PARSE.COM site. I blanked them when posting my quetion.

Comment: The only thing I can say is that make sure you AppId and ApiKey are valid. A 401 means you have invalid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question !

It appears that the required key (the second parameter in NetworkCredentials) should be the Master Key and not the REST API key.